# RecyclerView в RecyclerView или динамически добавлять View

Tags: android, kotlin

Из бэка приходят данные, формирую ViewHolder и отображаю в RecyclerView.

Ответ от бэка примерно такой структуры:

```
List<Data> response;

class Data {
    String title;
    String description;
    List<Info> informations;
}

class Info {
    String title;
    int value;
}
```

Из response формируется основной список, но еще в каждой строке RyceclerView нужно формировать вложенный список из `informations`(размер данного листа максимум 1-5 значений, вряд ли будет расти).

RecyclerView в RecyclerView или в ViewHolder делать addView ? Почему?

Comment: В посте по [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32333608/3671076) есть некоторые варианты реализации, есть +-

Answer (score 0):

Обратите ваше внимание на этот исчерпывающий пост. Думаю вам поможет
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60243208/add-items-within-nested-list-within-nested-recyclerview-in-a-recyclerview

Comment: А в чем плюс? Если вложенных объектов много, то плюс вижу в переиспользовании ViewHolder`ов, а когда вложенных объектов 2-3 как то непонятно в чем плюс дополнительных адаптеров и вложенных RV.